# jquery function calling asp function only working if inline

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function that calls an ASP/C# function. It works fine as long as I have it as inline script within the asp page. However when I move it into a file it literally appends the text into my page instead of calling the function like it does when the script code is inline. I have a suspicion of why it is happening, just not sure how to get around it. [image: INLINE:]
[image: INFILE]

Answer (score 1):

If you move the ASP.NET code out of your ASP.NET program source code and into a JS program's source code, then the C# compiler can't touch it.

[Use `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to store the data associated with the HTML elements you are dealing with on the elements, and then read it out of the DOM from JavaScript when you need it.

Comment: do you have an example that I could apply to my issue? I have tried this but no cigar:    var daelem = document.getElementById('main-content');
            daelem.dataset.append('<%=ctable("tbl1","sql.bts_summary.sql") %>');

Comment: @khemikal — Put the ASP.NET data generation code in ASP.NET program that generates the HTML. **Read** the data from there with JavaScript. Don't try to write it there from JavaScript. The ASP.NET isn't outputting the JavaScript so you can't write it from the JavaScript.

Comment: so what your saying is my method of putting it into a file will just straight up not work?

Comment: @khemikal — Correct. You can't move a chunk of your ASP.NET code into a .js file and have it still work. It's a different HTTP request and it's a file that won't be processed by the ASP.NET engine.